# Does referencing a custom object or field within a managed package need namespace?

Tags: apex, managed-package

This should be a simple question, but I have never built things from scratch before. Suppose I am having a custom_Obj__c and apex class A. Originally when I reference custom_Obj__c in class A I use custom_Obj__c as the API name.

And then when all the development is done, I put all the custom objects into the managed package with a namespace let's see abc. Both custom_Obj__c and class A are in this managed package.

But now the API name of custom_Obj__c has been changed into abc__custom_Obj__c. Do I need to update all the references in class A into abc__custom_Obj__c. It seems not needed to me. But just need to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The platform will do this for you automatically where needed. This includes code, validation rules, workflow rules, processes, triggers, and anywhere else it detects the name. There's a few exceptions to the rule, including non-merge fields, but these are usually rare if you use standard best practices. It's pretty hard to remember them, honestly, but make sure you test your package by installing to a test org before you unleash your app to customers.